# How to capture resolved data before the component in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm subscribing to a http method which cannot be changed. However, I need to call this method in my resolve, transform it and then access it in the component.

However, since the resolve returns "observerable", I'm not where do I capture the data and return the "changed" one.

E.g. 
`this.activatedRoute.snapshot.data['data']`  - this is how the component access the data right now. But I want to transform the "data" before it reaches the component.

The problem is :

I know about the operators and how to transform, I'm asking where should I do it? I cannot do it in resolve function as it returns the observable itself and I cannot do it in the http method that returns observable as I cannot change it. 
I'm looking for some hook in the pipeline where I can capture it.

Comment: Use the `map` operator on your `Observable` to transform the data

Comment: @user184994, I know about the operators and how to transform, I'm asking where should I do it? I cannot do it in resolve function as it returns the observable and I cannot do it in the http method as I cannot change it.

Comment: I'd need to see more of your code to give a good answer really

Comment: You can use the map operator in the resolver on the returned observable. Why should that be a problem: `resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<any>|Promise<any>|any {
    return this.backend.fetchTeam(route.params.id).pipe(map(()=> { //transform data}));
  }`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transform the data you could use something like a routeStateSerializer and store the route parameters or data directly when the route changes. Have a look at **ngrx/router-state** or **ngrx/router** for this purpose. But I suggest you to use the following approach and access the data when the observable stream reaches your component. If your http function in your injectable e.g. `ApiService` looks like this:

```js
httpFunction: Observable<YourDataType> () {
  return this.http.get<YourDataType>(`yourApi`);
}
```

Your can access the observable data in your component with RxJS 6 like this

```
// this.apiService.
httpFunction().pipe(
  map((data: YourDataType) => {
    // Do something with your data here
    // and don't forget to return it
  })
);
```

In RxJS 5 or before use the map function without the pipe.